# How to make turtles in netlogo die

Tags: netlogo

I'm having trouble in making the turtles die. 
Is it possible to make the turtles die after certain ticks?
If yes, how do you do you do it?
Please help!

Thanks,

Comment: @RaviJiyani curious why you point the OP at quora? I don't know anything about netlogo myself. Is there a better Stack Exchange for this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is the code if you want all the turtles to die after 100 ticks. `if ticks > 100 [ ask turtles [ die ] ]`. Of course, if all the turtles die, you probably want the simulation to stop instead.