# NetLogo- How to make turtles die after certain tick

Tags: netlogo

I'm having a hard time in making the turtles die after certain ticks. 
What's a procedure that I could use to let the turtles die after 10 ticks?

Comment: please explain why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516463/how-to-make-turtles-in-netlogo-die/28516571?noredirect=1#comment45494257_28516571 isn't what you need.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. Do you want them to die after 10 ticks of their (individual) life or 10 ticks of simulation?

### a) Let them live for 10 ticks

#### 1. Declare the birthday (or birthtick) variable at the beginning of program:

```
 turtles-own [
   birth-tick
 ]

; Note: you can define variables for specific breed if you are using breeds
```

#### 2. Set their birth-tick when you create them:

```
create-turtles 1 [ set birth-tick ticks ]
```

Note: make sure the `reset-ticks` is called before using ticks reporter

#### 3. Ask them to die

Somewhere (usually in a `go` procedure) call:

```
ask turtles[ if ticks - birth-tick > 10 [die] ]
```

Note: make sure you call `ticks` in your go procedure

### b) The end of the living world after 10 ticks

If you want to stop the simulation after 10 ticks call

```
if ticks > 10 [stop]
```