# How to Make Turtles Die after a Certain Tick - Preferential Attachment Model

Tags: netlogo

I have a following code for the modification of the preferential attachment model. After 500 ticks, I want some agents whose "fitness" are less than 10 to die. But there is an error: 
"The tick counter has not been started yet. Use RESET-TICKS.
error while turtle 0 running TICKS
  called by procedure MAKE-NODE
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'setup'"

Please let me know how to fix this error. I appreciate your help.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Setup Procedures ;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
turtles-own [fitness years characteristic birth-tick]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape turtles "circle"
  ;; make the initial network of two turtles and an edge
  make-node nobody        ;; first node, unattached
  make-node turtle 0      ;; second node, attached to first node
  reset-ticks
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Main Procedures ;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to-report random-binomial [n p] 
     report sum n-values n [ifelse-value (p > random-float 1) [1] [0]] 
end 


to go
  ;; new edge is green, old edges are gray
  if ticks >= 5000 [ stop ]
  ask links [ set color gray ]
  make-node find-partner         ;; find partner & use it as attachment
                                 ;; point for new node
  ask turtles [ if ticks - birth-tick > 500 [ if fitness <= 10 [die]]]
  tick
  if layout? [ layout ]
end

;; used for creating a new node
to make-node [old-node]
  crt 1
  [
    set birth-tick ticks
    set color red
    set characteristic random-binomial 10 0.2
    set years random-float 10
    set fitness characteristic * years
    if old-node != nobody
      [ create-link-with old-node [ set color green ]
        ;; position the new node near its partner
        move-to old-node
        fd 8

     ]

  ]

end


to-report find-partner
  let total random-float sum [(count link-neighbors) * fitness] of turtles
  let partner nobody
  ask turtles
  [
    let nc (count link-neighbors) * fitness
    ;; if there's no winner yet...
    if partner = nobody
    [
      ifelse nc > total
        [ set partner self ]
        [ set total total - nc ]
    ]
  ]
  report partner
end
```

Comment: My question is related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593889/netlogo-how-to-make-turtles-die-after-certain-tick I did as this question suggested, but it did not work...

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `reset-ticks` before you call `make-node`

```
to setup
   clear-all
   reset-ticks
   set-default-shape turtles "circle"
   ;; make the initial network of two turtles and an edge
   make-node nobody        ;; first node, unattached
   make-node turtle 0      ;; second node, attached to first node  
end
```

that is it.

Comment: I would suggest going with bergant's answer. `reset-ticks` should only be called once a model has been fully set up.

Comment: I can see were you are coming from especially if you are using plots that use division . I would argue that since Netlogo models tend to so short and clearly written that that kind discipline is less necessary.

Comment: Seth, could you provide another practical example aside from plotting where calling reset-ticks at the beginning of setup may cause some issues? As this point, I agree with King-Ink.

Comment: @mattsap As I understand it is a modification of preferential attachment model from standard library. When calling premature `reset-ticks` you should expect the _Degree Distribution (log-log)_ plot will fail to evaluate `max [count link-neighbors] of turtles` and stop with error: _Can't find the maximum of a list with no numbers_.

Comment: Frankly, I think the plotting problem is more than enough all by itself. Why invite trouble? But it also means that the view will be redrawn at the wrong time. (And, it is likely that more features in future versions of NetLogo will be built around this.)

Comment: Note that "the plotting problem" doesn't have to be plot code that blows up — it might be something a hundred times worse than that, namely plot code that silently plots incorrect data.

Comment: If reset-ticks did not call tick would t solve the issue?

Comment: @King-Ink I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @SethTisue I guess Kink-Ink is talking about new primitive like `reset-ticks-without-update-plots`. It might be more elegant than catching errors with `carefully`.

Comment: As I see it and y'all are definitely the ones to tell me I am wrong. reset-ticks does 2 things 1) sets up ticks and plots and such 2) performs one tick. What if the two bits where separated?

Comment: Technically in current version it 1) resets counter, 2) setup plots, 3) updates plots and 4) updates display. From design point of view (if I understand correctly from what Seth explained) it is kind of a state changer when the model is set and simulation can begin - so it might do even more in the future.

Comment: Do steps 3 4 run when we call Tick?

Comment: It would be nice for me if reset-ticks just ran 1 and 2 and not 3 and 4. Alternately a reset-ticks-with-no-initial-tick. but of course I have not looked through the code and I am sure Y'all got your reasons

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to call `reset-ticks` at the end of the `setup` procedure. 
This procedure also plots initial state (when any plots are defined).
I think it would be best to amend your `make-node` procedure and change your `set birth-tick ticks` line to:

```
carefully [ set birth-tick ticks ][ set birth-tick 0 ]
```

Now it will work either before or after calling `reset-ticks`.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `carefully` is necessary here, because there's no more convenient way to test whether the tick counter has been reset yet. I'd call it a hole in the language.

Comment: @SethTisue Yes, and before [v 5.0](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#v50) tick counter was initially set to 0.